# How to run two function parallelly and send response of fastest function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

**So I got Asked in the technical interview this question:**
#NodeJs, #Javascript
let's say we have two weather API that has to be run parallelly.

- Condition1:The fastest one to produce the result should be sent as a
  response.
- Condition2:If one  Fails and the other succeeds the succeeding result
  should be sent as a response.

I have not been able to find the solution to this for a long time.

---

So How am I Supposed to choose between the two of them?

Comment: [`Promise.race`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race)?

Comment: `Promise.any()`

Comment: Can you provide me a code example if it's not much trouble for you?

Comment: I think `Promise.race` doesn't fulfill the second condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`Promise.any`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any) as it returns a single promise that fulfills as soon as any of the promises in the iterable fulfills.

[`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) will return the first promise resolved whether it succeeded or failed.

[FOR EXAMPLE](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-does-promise-any-method-differs-from-promise-race-method-in-javascript/)

```js
let rejected_promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  reject("Rejected Promise.....");
});

let first_resolved_promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve("Resolved after 1 second");
  }, 1000);
});

let second_resolved_promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve("Resolved after 2 seconds");
  }, 2000);
});



let result_1 = Promise.any([
  rejected_promise,
  first_resolved_promise,
  second_resolved_promise,
]);

result_1.then((data) => console.log("Any's data: " + data)).catch(e => console.log(e));

let result_2 = Promise.race([
  rejected_promise,
  first_resolved_promise,
  second_resolved_promise,
]);

result_2.then((data) => console.log("Race's data: " + data)).catch(e => console.log(e));
```